# Splitting Jenkins Job to run concurrently

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation

Does anyone know of a way to split a single Jenkins job into parts and run them concurrently/parallel?

For example if I have a job that runs tests which take 30 minutes, is there a way I can break this job into three 10 minute runs that run at the same time but in three different instances

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split the tasks into 3 jobs and run them on 3 different instances?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540591/parallel-test-execution-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Create new jobs, call it f.e. **Test** . You should select the job type based on the type of the root job.

If you have a Maven Job type, you can set the workspace directory under **build** -> **advanced**. Freestyle Job type has this option directly under **project** -> **advanced**.

Set for all jobs the same working directory. The root job will compile and all other jobs uses the same working directory to use the compiled output.

For the test jobs add the test execution as build step and differ here the tests which should be executed.

Edit your root job and remove there the excution of the long running tests. You can call there the three jobs now. But you need the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

The downside of this way, you need enough jenkins executors to handle all tests jobs.

Comment: Thanks @CSchulz, in the advanced of build in a maven project I have also  noticed a check box " Build modules in parallel " . Would this be useful? Cheers.

Comment: I don't think it will help you, because you have to seperate the tests in own modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jenkins 1.x, I would suggest trying the multijob plugin - I've successfully used it to split a single job into a parent job plus multiple child jobs:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

If you're using Jenkins 2.x, then try out the pipeline feature :) It makes running parallel tasks very easy:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multiple-threads

If you want, I believe you can also use pipelines in Jenkins 1.x by means of a plugin. I haven't looked into that, though.